# JavaScript logical reasoning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page `a.jsp` with the following elements elements

```
--a1--
--a2--
--a3--

<select onChange="cht('1');" id="a1"><option>H263</option><option>H264</option></select>

<div class="Text" onclick="cht('2');" disabled>
<img   src="http://mocii.com/uploads/2011/01/beautiful-fractal-wallpapers.jpeg"  height="100"   width="100"  /></div>
<div  id="a3" disabled>a3</div> 


function cht(index){
    var id = parseInt(index)+1;
  var e = document.getElementById("a"+id);alert("a"+id);
  e.removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

How can I block user action on `a2` and `a3` till `a1` is not selected, and if `a1` is selected then open `a2`, if `a2` is selected then open `a3`, 
where `a1` is my select tag, `a2` is my images on click of those images i perform some operation on `a3`. There is no link between `a1` and `a2`, but both are required for `a3`.

Comment: I guess that was a _What have you tried so far, please show some code_ downvote. If so, I have to agree: can you provide a piece of HTML to show how these a1, a2, a3 things are structured? can you clarify how you intend these things to be _selected_ or _open_? can you provide some of the jquery you tried and tell us how it isn't what you are expecting? That kind of things will help people understand your question and answer it precisely.

Comment: these are the 2 elements and first one is a select tag on select tag i need to unblock the last portion shown in this iamge and then the chart portin : http://postimg.org/image/6m5kr8st1/

Comment: @Volune i have added the data please check

Comment: And what is `a3`? why can't you add the actual/sample html elements? otherwise how will we write the code? Do you expect something like like `("a3").onclick` ??

Comment: i told you a1 is select tag ,a2 is group of iamges and a3 is a chart (from highcharts api)that will get rendered based on a1 and a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.
Lets say a1, a2 and a3 are buttons

```
<button index="1" onclick="chng-status();" id="a1">a1</button>
<button index="2" id="a2" onclick="chng-status();" disabled>a2</button>
<button index="3" id="a3" disabled>a3</button>
```

now, lets say you clicked on "a1", then this what will you do

```
<script>
    function chng-status(index){
      var e = document.getElementById("a"+index+1);
      e.removeAttribute("disabled");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this example not working ..

Comment: this is some how helpful but i wanted select tag and group of iamges in a1 and a2 so the methods will be diffrent ,let me implement then accept you answer (y)

Comment: not working for images :(

Comment: you want to click on image ? do you have it wrapped in a link ?

Comment: Don't make up custom attributes, use `data-index`

Comment: yeah i wanted the 2nd element to be a group of images which i wanted to be disabled at first time

Answer (score 0):

you can define an object like :

```
var clickStatus= {
     a1Clicked:false,
     a2Clicked:false,
     a3Clicked:false,
};
```

and when the click event happend use this object to set each of them to true. like:

```
clickStatus.a1Clicked=true;
```

with this and some IF you can manage it.
Hope it Helps.